# Adding abbrevs in ess-mode

Tags: abbrev, ess

I can't seem to get abbrevs working in ess-mode when editing .R files.

I have ess-mode hook to activate abbrev-mode, but I get no expansion for my global abbrevs.

When I do `add-mode-abbrev` I can add an abbrev, but it is not written to my abbrev file and of course doesn't get ever expanded (after `read-abbrev-file` or restart).

If I by hand add something like this into my abbrev file and reload:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'ess-mode-abbrev-table
'(
    ("-=" "<-" nil 0)
))
```

it doesn't work either.

How can I make ess-mode aware of my abbrevs?

Comment: ESS provides an electric underscore, meaning if you type "_", it inserts "<-". That might be easier than typing "-=" anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on abbrev as well and it seems [only word-constituent characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expanding-Abbrevs.html) can be part of an abbrev. Thus I don't think you can use `"-="` as an abbrev. Have you tried using other characters?